# Stop Scrolling Div at end of Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I am creating a TV Guide and have implemented previous and next buttons to scroll to the next amount of hours however when i click this the scrolling is continuous with no end point. Is there any way to stop this at the at a specific point? i.e each hour cell is 100px therefore 24x100=2400px which the scrolling should stop at. The jquery which i am using for this is below:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var $item = $('.timeCell, .cellProgram'), 
    visible = 2, 
    index = 0, 
    endIndex = ( $item.length / visible ) - 1; 

$('div#arrowR').click(function(){
    if(index < endIndex ){
      index++;
      $item.animate({'left':'-=246px'});
    }
});

$('div#arrowL').click(function(){
    if(index > 0){
      index--;            
      $item.animate({'left':'+=246px'});
    }
});
```

});

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$selector.offset().top` with `$selector.outerHeight()` to get the bottom postition of container.
Then add an eventListenner scroll event, to check if current position is match your condition.

Example :

```
 var $selector = $('.class-selector');
 if($selector.length == 0) {
    return;
 }
 var triggerPosition = $selector.offset().top + $selector.outerHeight(); // position of container's bottom

 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
      var windowTopPosition = $(window).scrollTop()
        , windowBottomPosition = windowTopPosition  + $(window).height(); // depend on your idea, use the top or bottom as currentPosition
     var currentPosition = windowBottomPosition' // in this i.e, I use the bottom.

     if( currentPosition > triggerPosition) {
           // trigger if those bottom meet each other , such as:
           stopScroll();
     } else { 
          // trigger when windows is above the container's bottom, such as:
          continuousScroll(); 
     }
  });
```

Hope it helps.